# JavaFX TableView updateItem slow for ComboBox

Tags: performance, javafx, combobox, tableview

I made a dynamic ComboBox (initialized inside my TableView's CellFactory class) to show calls list. It needs to read the ID number from ID TableColumn and then get from a DB table the calls matching that ID. All went well but since TableView is not fully initialized while I set up CellFactory for my table, I can't read ID at runtime and so I moved this code to updateItem() method, setting call list cell factory.

In updateItem() (MyCellFactory):

```
 listCallCombo.setCellFactory(listview -> new ImageCallListCell(id_num));

 listCallCombo.setButtonCell(new ImageCallListCell(id_num));
```

ImageCallListCell:

```
public class ImageCallListCell extends ListCell<String> {

private Label label = null;
private int id;

ImageCallListCell(int id) {
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (item == null || empty) {

        setItem(null);
        setGraphic(null);

    } else {
        setText(item);

        ImageView image = Utils.getImageViewByName("call");


        if (image != null && !item.equals("")) {
            image.setFitHeight(20);
            image.setFitWidth(22);
            String call = "Error";
            if (item.equals("0")) {
                call = "Add Call...";
            } else if (id != 0 && !item.equals("-1")) {

                call = ListCallHandler.getCallFromIDandIndex(id, Integer.parseInt(item));
            } 
            label = new Label(call, image);


        }
        setGraphic(label);
    }
}
```

}

Where ListCallHandler returns an array of calls doing a one-time fetch with database.
Doing this made my code work but of course setting every time ButtonCell and CellFactory for every line made my table slow to scroll.

How can I better handle this, to have better performance?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here's ListCallHandler code snippet:

```
    public static List<Map> getCalls() {
        ResultSet list = DbUpdate.run_query("select * from memo", Utils.DBName);
        List mCalls = new LinkedList();
        try {
            while (list.next()) {
                Map call = new HashMap();
                String callstring = list.getString("Lista Chiamate");
                call.put("id", list.getInt("id"));
                call.put("chiamate", callstring);
                mCalls.add(call);
             }
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ...
            }

  public static String getCallFromIDandIndex(int id, int index) {
        List<String> c = ListCallHandler.getCallsFromID(id, true);
        String result = "(No Calls)";
        if (index < c.size()) {
            result = c.get(index);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

getCallsFromID() simply run getCalls and then reorganize data into an array.

Thank you again!

**EDIT 2**

getImageViewByName():

```
 public static ImageView getImageViewByName(String name) {
        return Utils.initImageView("raw/" + name + ".png");
    }

    public static ImageView initImageView(String path) {
        BufferedImage bf = null;
        WritableImage wr = null;

        try {
            bf = ImageIO.read(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
            if (bf != null) {
                wr = new WritableImage(bf.getWidth(), bf.getHeight());
                PixelWriter pw = wr.getPixelWriter();
                for (int x = 0; x < bf.getWidth(); x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < bf.getHeight(); y++) {
                        pw.setArgb(x, y, bf.getRGB(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR LOADING PICTURE " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return new ImageView(wr);

    }
```

I managed to make it less painfull to scroll with a little trick, but it's still very poor experience, here's what I did:

```
tableview.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
                if (scrollEvent.getEventType() == ScrollEvent.SCROLL_FINISHED) {
                    ListCallHandler.canUpdateCalls = true;
                } else if (scrollEvent.getEventType() == ScrollEvent.SCROLL_STARTED) {
                    ListCallHandler.canUpdateCalls = false;
                } else {
                    ListCallHandler.canUpdateCalls = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

And then I checked canUpdateCalls variable before drawing cells in ImageCallListCell. When scrolling slowly, it's good. If you skip to mid list, it hangs up for 4-5 seconds...

Comment: Is the image always the same (from the hard-coded parameter to your `Utils` method, it looks like it).

Comment: yes, it is, it's a phone icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky. If you make database calls that may take time to execute, you should do so on a background thread. In particular, the `updateItem(...)` method in a cell implementation is called frequently, so you should minimize the amount of work that is done in that method.

The tricky part here is that cells may be reused frequently enough that if you start the database call in a background thread, `updateItem(...)` could be called again with a new item before the preceding database call completes. So you need to be able to cancel existing calls. The [`javafx.concurrent.Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) class has this functionality, though I have never used it in this context.

This makes only a small difference, but there is no need to create a new `ImageView` every time `updateItem()` is called. Create the `ImageView` once. From your code it looks as though the image is always the same, though you could update the image view with `setImage(...)` if you need. (A similar thing is true for the label.)

A cell implementation like this should work better:

```
public class ImageCallListCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private Label label ;
    private int id;

    private Service<String> dbService ;

    ImageCallListCell(int id) {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.id = id;
        label = new Label();
        ImageView image = Utils.getImageViewByName("call");
        image.setFitHeight(20);
        image.setFitWidth(22);
        label.setGraphic(image);

        dbService = new Service<String>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<String> createTask() {
                return new Task<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String call() throws Exception {
                        return ListCallHandler.getCallFromIDandIndex(id, Integer.parseInt(getItem()));
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        dbService.setOnSucceeded(e -> label.setText(dbService.getValue()));
        dbService.setOnFailed(e -> {
            Throwable exc = dbService.getException();
            // log exception, etc
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        // note this won't do anything as you have ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY:
        setText(item);

        // cancel any running database task:
        dbService.cancel();

        if (item == null || empty) {

            setGraphic(null);

        } else {


            if (!item.equals("")) {
                if (item.equals("0")) {
                    label.setText("Add Call...");
                } else if (id != 0 && !item.equals("-1")) {
                    label.setText("Loading from database...");
                    // run new database task in background:
                    dbService.restart();
                } 

            } else {
                // should set label's text to something here...
            }
            setGraphic(label);
        }
    }

}
```

With this implementation, when the cell needs to contact the database, it uses the `Service` to do so on a background thread. The `onSucceeded` handler for the service will update the label's text when the database call is complete. The call to `dbService.cancel()` ensures that there aren't multiple database calls whose results will compete for the same cell.

There are a couple of other quirks with your implementation, such as setting the text when you have content display set to `GRAPHIC_ONLY`, and not updating the label under all circumstances, which I pointed out in comments in the code. And it's better to create UI elements once per cell, and modify them in the `updateItem(...)` method, rather than create new UI controls every time.

---

**Update**

One other thing to notice is that you are repeatedly loading the same image from a stream, which is a lot of unnecessary work (and consumes a lot of unnecessary memory). Multiple image views can share the same image, so you could cache the images. For example;

```
public class Utils {

    private static Map<String, Image> imageCache = new WeakHashMap<>();

    private static Image getImage(String name) {
        return imageCache.computeIfAbsent(name, this::readImage);
    }

    private static Image readImage(String name) {
        BufferedImage bf = null ;
        Image img = null ;
        try {
            bf = ImageIO.read(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("raw/+name+".png"));
            img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bf, null);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.err.println("ERROR LOADING PICTURE " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return img ;
    }

    public static ImageView getImageViewByName(String name) {
        return new ImageView(getImage(name));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your quick answer. I optimized my code with your suggestions, but I realize that on Windows is still very slow (on Mac it's 10x faster or even more!)... Can you help me figuring out why? I update the OP with methods I call from ListCallHandler

Comment: Did the changes actually make a difference (i.e. was it previously slower on the Mac). (I use a Mac, so probably not a good idea to ask me why your windows machine is slow... ;).)

Comment: On Mac I didn't notice visible difference... I tried on different Windows machines, same results. Disabling drawing only for that combo makes scrolling quick on Windows too (seems incredible ahahah).

Comment: What is `Utils.getImageViewByName(...)` doing?

Comment: Updated OP, also with a little awful trick I did to reduce drawing.

Comment: See update. You seem to be repeatedly loading the same image from a resource, which you don't need to do. Just cache the images and re-use them in different `ImageView`s

Comment: Thank you James!! It was the real issue, caching icons made everything smooth!! :D